# PayPal showing Error when work with sandbox account

Tags: android, paypal

I am Android Developer and work with PayPal. I have done integration and login is also a success on PayPal sandbox account but when I click on pay option button then this Error occurs so Please help me how to solve.

Error: "There was a problem setting up this payment please visit the PayPal website to check your account"

[image]

Comment: Have you got the solution then please share your answer please because I am also facing the same issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to process a sandbox payment in USD currency with India country sandbox accounts (both buyer and seller accounts are India country accounts). Due to banking regulations, India merchants can't receive a payment from an India buyer in USD. Kindly use the other country sandbox accounts as buyers for processing successful sandbox payments.

Answer (score 0):

Check Currency, and also the account you are testing with, try with a client sandbox account.